# Custom configuration entry in environment.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I use EmberJS 2.4.2. I want to use environment.js file to handle custom configuration entries. E.g.

```
var ENV = {
  APP: {
    myKey: "defaultValue"
  }
};
```

It works fine in development mode, but after I perform 'ember build -prod', the variable is inaccessible - in the production mode the variable is 'undefined'.

I use the key in following manner:

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';
(...)
ENV.APP.myKey
```

What am I doing wrong and how to resolve the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The variable was undefined only if I merged my client-side app (written with Ember) into index.html of my server-side and I did not copy the meta tag with new config/environment definition.

After doing so, the configuration key was easily accessible.